# Fastest C++ map for worst-case time execution in a real time app?

Tags: c++, audio, hashmap, hashtable, real-time

I'm trying to figure out how I want to store timed events in a real time audio app that may hop around in time a lot, and needs to run with the lowest latency possible. Basically the engine knows what time 'now' is, but 'now' may be non-linear, and there be multiple 'nows' in the future. I'm wondering if:

a) a C++ map of some time keyed by time values is even feasible, when there could be thousands of entries
b) which map or hash table implementation will give me the best performance where best means lowest worst case execution, not lowest average. An implementation that even once in a while takes a really long time will be unusable, something with a more deterministic result would be better.
c) for a bunch of events sharing the same now, should one use some sort of hash multi map or link a list of all events at a given time?

I'm open to any other suggestions of how to do this too, or pointers to resources. Time is encoded in it's own format, representing sections:bars:beats:ticks

thanks!
iain

Comment: Has anyone any experience with Judy Arrays for this type of thing?

Comment: Wow, they look like a nice data structure! I don't know how complicated the implementation is, but if you could get them to use lookaside lists for guaranteed fixed-time allocation, they might be the winner for your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing can save you from having to **profile** your code and see for yourself.

Make the data type as easy to change as possible, keep everything modular and parameterised, and then just run some tests.

Start with `std::multimap` and `std::unordered_multimap`, with time as the key. Both should have pretty good performance. Try a few different allocators, too.

Comment: I'm too new to vote that up, so I'll just say thanks instead!